Axiomatic and formal establishment of Plato's dialectics
After years of studying Plato I have seen some attempts to formalize somehow Plato's dialectics. To be more precise, I have found writers who present Plato's dialectics (especially as it is presented in Phaedros, Parmenides, Politikos, Sophistes) in a more or less "algorithmic-step analytical" way. Though I have never found a strictly formal, axiomatic establishment. I cannot prove it but I am intuitively almost sure that Plato's dialectics can be formalized. Does anyone know something about that?

"I have found writers..." references, please.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Nicholas White, Richard Robinson, Alfred Taylor, Clarence Lewis Protin etc.

Benson describes Plato's dialectic as follows, "a process of identifying and drawing out the consequences of propositions, known as hypotheses, in order to answer the question at hand, and a process of confirming or justifying those hypotheses." The key ingredient here is 'creative' generation of hypotheses to answer questions, and I am not sure how you imagine that being formalized. "Logic of discovery" has been talked about, but formalizing it is a tall order, see Kelly.

Look at Krabbe-Walton, Formal dialectical systems and their uses in the study of argumentation, "we offer an explanation of how formal dialectical systems are useful for modeling important aspects of argumentation, like dealing with fallacies.". I am not sure if this is the sort of thing you are looking for.

@Conifold about your first comment; The description you quote is out of my mind: it describes partly and insufficiently the subject. If you read my question, you will see the works of Plato that contain the dialectics of division, definition, relation between ideas (μετοχή). Ι will check Krabbe-Walton -thanks.
